# Contradiction in a type theory where "Type : Type"?

Tags: logic, reference-request, type-theory

I read that if you have a define a type theory (by that I mean a system similar to [Martin-Löf type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory)), where we have $\mathsf{Type} : \mathsf{Type}$, we can prove a contradiction, via Girard's Paradox.

However "canonical" version of Girard's Paradox proves a contradiction in the more complicated System U and System U$^-$, so most of the references I could dig up (like [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kw/scans/hurkens95tlca.pdf) or [this](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~coquand/paradox.ps)) seem to spend a lot of time dealing with the confusing details of the different sorts of System U. Since, as far as I understand it, System U (and after that System U$^-$) was intended to circumvent the problem arising from $\mathsf{Type} : \mathsf{Type}$, I would expect it to be significantly easier to prove a contradiction from $\mathsf{Type} : \mathsf{Type}$.

If so, does anybody have a reference to somebody doing that?

The only thing I could find is the second answer to [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Girards-paradox), but it doesn't explain how the two terms $elem$ and $subset$ are defined.

Comment: The paradox of trees is a simple paradox that occurs in Martin Lof type systems. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f2f3/30b27f1d7ca99c2550f96581a4400c209ef8.pdf Which may be helpful to you.

Comment: @QthePlatypus That looks interesting! Thank you!